# Blinking when updating value very often

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, dom

I have been making a stopwatch in Javascript and I have implemented all the functionality successfully. However, as the timer is updated every often, every 10 milliseconds, the chrome dev console shows that the webpage sometimes draw nothing in the stopwatch field, causing the field to make a sudden blink as the time appears once again.

I wonder how I can accomplish to have a blink-free static stopwatch.

host: http://folk.ntnu.no/nikolahe/assignment8/stopwatch.html

stopwatch.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e){

    var interval;
    var state = 0;
    var display = document.getElementById('display-area');
    var offset;
    var clock = 0;

    function updateTimer() {
        clock += delta();
        var time = format(clock);
        if (time != "") {
            display.value = time;
        }
    }

    function format(clock) {
        var timer = new Date(clock);
        var currentHours = timer.getHours()-1;
        var currentMinutes = timer.getMinutes();
        var currentSeconds = timer.getSeconds();
        var currentMilliseconds = timer.getMilliseconds();

        currentHours = ( currentHours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentHours;
        currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
        currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;
        currentMilliseconds = ( currentMilliseconds < 100 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMilliseconds;
        return currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + "." + currentMilliseconds;
    }

    function delta() {
        var now = Date.now();
        d = now - offset;
        offset = now;
        return d;
    }

    function toggle() {
        console.log(state);
        if (!interval) {
            console.log("start");
            offset = Date.now();
            interval = setInterval(updateTimer, 10);
        } else {
            console.log("stop");
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
    }

    function reset() {
        if(interval) {
            toggle();
        }
        display.value = "00:00:00.000"
        clock = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('toggle-button').addEventListener("click", toggle);
    document.getElementById('reset-button').addEventListener("click", reset);
})
```

stopwatch.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <script src="stopwatch.js"></script>
        <style>
            body { text-align: center; margin-top: 200px; font-family: courier;}
            #display-area { font-size: 20pt; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <output id="display-area">00:00:00.000</output>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="toggle-button">Start / Stop</button>
            <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working on latest chrome without any blinking, so I can't recreate it and can't tell if this solution is correct, but it could be a solution.

It may be a problem caused by the browser itself. The human eye can only see noticeable changes every 16ms, your loop definitely runs in less time than that. The problem might just be the browser not wanting you to update an element's content before 16ms than that. If you said that it runs about every 10ms, you'll have an entire cycle (16ms) every 4 in which the value will not be displayed. This is only a theory and I can't prove it.

Instead of `interval = setInterval(updateTimer, 10);`, try `interval-= 16; window.setTimeout(updateTimer, 16)`, which should do stuff only every 16 or more ms

Comment: if this is not correct then it's probably something related

Comment: Actually i did some more work in the console and it turned out my code didn't add a trailing zero in all cases, for example (01, 05), but in (009, 014). So i added code to manually add a trailing zero to these cases. Turned out perfectly!

Comment: perfect! And thank you for the 'correct answer' even though the I've done nothing XD